# Programmatically evaluating expressions / debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, add-in

I'm writing a Visual Studio Add-In, nothing serious, just to experiment.
I need to evaluate a piece of code when the debugger is running, and It's being very hard for me to google / search in SO for it.

Let's say that hovering `Person1.Name` it will display `"JustAName"`. I want from my add-in code, when a command is executed, evaluate the string `"Person1.Name"` (which is in the debugger context) and get the string `"JustAName"`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Debugger.GetExpression()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc701284.aspx) method.

Comment: Actually, It was helpful. Using the debugger instance in my plugin's  _applicationObject it's exactly what I wanted